# Kendo Grid Not showing Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to bind Data from database to KendoUI Grid but Data is not Showed up... I am getting data from database successfully converting into serialized code but data does not showed up in Kendo Grid.. plz help me...

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
<div id="grid"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">           
            $(document).ready(function(){

                 $("#grid").kendoGrid({

                    dataSource:
                    {
                    type:"odata",
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting:true,
                    pageSize:100,
                    transport:
                    {
                        read: 
                        {
                        url:"Fetchdata.aspx",
                         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "odata",
                        jsonReader: 
                                 {
                                    root: "rows",  
                                    page: "page",
                                    total: "total",
                                    records: "records",
                                    repeatitems: false               

                                }                  

                        }
                    }
                    },
                    height:100,
                    scrollable:
                    {
                        virtual: true
                    },
                    sortable: true,
                    columns: [
                         "dptId",
                          { title: "Name", field: "dptName" },
                          { title: "Description", field: "dptdescription" }
                              ]                                         
               });                
            });
        </script>
        </div>
```

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    Response.Write(GetData());
    Response.End();

}


protected string GetData()
{

    EmployeeBM empbm = new EmployeeBM();
    List < Departement> list= new List<Departement>();

    list = empbm.BindDepartment();
    return GridData(1, 1,list.Count, list);
}

public string GridData(int noOfPages, int startPage, int noOfRecords, List<Departement> list)
{
    var gridData = new
                       {
                           total = noOfPages,   
                           page = startPage,   
                           records = noOfRecords,   
                           rows = list,            
                       };

    var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
    return jsonSerializer.Serialize(gridData);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see quite a few issues in your code:

- The `dataType` cannot be set to "odata". Try "json". To quote the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

  > Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
- The Kendo DataSource `type` is also set to "odata" but your page is clearly not an OData service. Remove that.
- You are setting `jsonReader` which is not supported by the Kendo DataSource. I guess you need to use the [schema](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schema-object) setting.